# Which PHP Editors are supporting the Go To Implementation functionality?

Tags: php, visual-studio, ide

Which PHP Editors for Windows are supporting the Go To Implementation functionality as Visual Studio is doing?

Go to implementation (F12) in Visual Studio has a contextual behavior which may change between go to file, go to symbol definition , go to method definition , go to variable definition and so on.

Which IDE for PHP are supporting the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **NuSphere PhpED Version 15.0** => no
- **Zend Studio 11** => crashing on my environment
- **JetBrain WebStorm 8** => no
- **JetBrain PHP Storm 8** => yes, it has some Resharper typical functionality as Refactor\Rename Navigate to file Navigate to implementation, Find Usages